# Should we delete blocklist tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [blocklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/blocklist) apparently is misused, out of 11 questions where it's used ,  it's used for block devices, on other - for blocking specific websites. There's also no usage-guide for that tag.

Comment: We should block the [tag:blocklist] and blacklist it

Comment: @muru  can I just say, that the comment is very ironic :) block the blocklist

Comment: Thanks.. But I never can reach [the levels seen in Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request?sort=votes).

Comment: I literally just burst out laughing at "I wanna delete the [Internet]" question. Good link, muru

Comment: We should drag @Zanna into this question as she spent a good deal of time nuking all questions with the [tag:UbuntuOne] tag. Her expertise might come in very handy.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you can only ping someone who has already interacted with a post. But this question seems to be about a non-existent tag *innocent face*

Comment: @zanna strikes again with her awesomeness